Cannot see grub
enter image description hereWas using windows 10 with Ubuntu in dual boot but after accidentally updating the bios i cannot see the grub, used the bootmgr path command but it didn't work and also tried to disable secure boot but nothing happened and my boot priority looks like this

What brand/model system? Did you update UEFI which you normally should do, but Windows normally does it or did you totally reinstall Windows? Reinstall of Windows may erase Linux partitions. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
